# Python, Beatbox - Return all available fields

Tags: python, python-2.7, salesforce, beatbox

I'm trying to run a query into Salesforce that returns the names and API names of all the fields with an associated object using beatbox.

Has anyone done this before? Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example of that in demo.py that comes with Beatbox,

```
    desc = svc.describeSObjects("Account")
    for f in desc[sf.fields:]:
        print "\t" + str(f[sf.name])
```

will print all the API names of the fields on Account, if you want the labels as well, that'd be str(f[sf.label])

Comment: what is the type of sf ?

Comment: its beatbox._tPartnerNS. see https://github.com/superfell/Beatbox/blob/master/examples/demo.py

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer results in this error: "TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method"

This works:

```
import beatbox

api = beatbox.PythonClient()  
api.login(sf_username, sf_pw+sf_token)
obj_desc = api.describeSObjects("Order")[0]
names = [name for name in obj_desc.fields]
```

Comment: only if you're using the fork of beatbox that added PythonClient

Answer (score 0):

**For me this works like a charm :)**

I Faced the same error : got "TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method"

I got all available fields, labels, data-type easily as :
`

```
import beatbox
api = beatbox.PythonClient()  
api.login(sf_username, sf_pw+sf_token)
fields = api.describeSObjects("Account")[0].fields
all_table_list = [ {'name':key[1].name,'label':key[1].label,'type':key[1].type} for key  in fields.iteritems()]
```

`